# focus on daynamically created datepicker on click of span date calender

Tags: jquery, html

I have created dynamic datepicker as shown in this example http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/98/ but I have to put glyphicon-calendar after input, but the click event of calender datepicker is not working on the glyphicon-calendar

I have tried below code but it didn't work.....

```
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control textmodify_newSchedule datepicker_recurring_start" > 
    <span class="input-group-addon datepicker_recurring_start_calender"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>

 $(function () {
          $('body').on('focus',".datepicker_recurring_start", function(){
                $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
          });
          $('.datepicker_recurring_start_calender').click(function() {
                $(".datepicker_recurring_start").focus();
          });
    });
```

Please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the HTML dynamically, then you cannot bind this way:

```
  $('.datepicker_recurring_start_calender').click(function() {
        $(".datepicker_recurring_start").focus();
  });
```

You have to do something like this:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.datepicker_recurring_start_calender', function() {
        $(".datepicker_recurring_start").focus();
  });
```

Comment: I have tried this but it gave me "jquery.js:4641 Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function" error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind event listeners on dynamically created elements. But you can bind events on the `document` element like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker_recurring_start_calender', function(e) {
  console.log(this);
  $(".datepicker_recurring_start").focus();
});
```

Comment: I had tried this code also and receive the same error "jquery.js:4641 Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function"

Comment: I edited my answer, please check if your console logs `this`

Comment: console log shows me <span class="input-group-addon datepicker_recurring_start_calender"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span> this